# In Rails my RESTful route is throwing a 404 even though I have configrued the route in config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, config, restful-url

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have a controller with one method

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController

   def states
      @country = Country.find params[:country_id]
      @states = @country.states
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: @states.to_json }
      end
   end

end
```

In my config/routes.rb file I set up

```
resources :countries do
    get :state, on: :member #-> url.com/countries/:country_id/states/
end
```

However, when I visit the URL

```
http://mydomein.devbox.com:3000/countries/38/states
```

I get a 404.  What else do I need to do to get this to work?

**Edit:** I edited my coffeescript to match the suggestion (adding a content type), but this still results in a 404 ...

```
@update_states = (countryElt, stateElt) ->
   url = "/countries/" + $(countryElt).val() + "/states"
   $.ajax
     url: url
     type: 'GET'
     contentType: 'application/json'
     success: (data) ->
       for key, value of data
         $(stateElt).find('option').remove().end()
         $(stateElt).append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server cannot find a route because the controller and/or the request are not properly written.

First, when touching `config/routes.rb` in rails, you need to restart the server (you can apply this rule to basically all modified files in config folder).

**EDIT**

Second, your `resources` function is incorrect, try this:

```
resources :countries do
     get :states # >> url.com/countries/:country_id/states
end
```

With your current config, your server is looking for a `countries#state` action, though your controller/action is named `countries#states`

**END OF EDIT**

Second, your request and your controller don't match. You're writing a request for an HTML response, but your controller only responds to json. Try setting a `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header in your request, or directly write the format in the request: `http://your-url.com/countries/38/states.json`.

If you also need your response in HTML, you need to add this format to the controller method:

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController

  def states
    @country = Country.find params[:country_id]
    @states = @country.states
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # if your views were generated you may not need to specify a template or its variables
      format.json { render json: @states.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

With this both routes (html and json) will be found by your server. Your original url should work with that !

Comment: Since I'm dealing with jQuery ajax calls, I just want to focus on the JSON route.  I included my ajax call in my question to demonstrate that I've added teh "contentType" header.  However, I'm still getting a 404.  Further, I even changed the URL to be "states.json" but got a 404 from that as well.

Comment: Just updated my answer, please check and comment if you're running into a similar issue